# This expression is not callable. Type 'Promise<void>' has no call signatures. (Mongodb-Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, node-modules

I am trying to connect mongodb with node (ts).
while connecting I am getting this error "This expression is not callable.   Type 'Promise<void>' has no call signatures"

1. data.ts

   ```
   import mongoDb, { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
   import dotenv from "dotenv";

   dotenv.config();

   export const mongoDBConnection = MongoClient.connect(
       process.env.MONGODB_URL as string,

   )
   .then(async (client) => {
       const database = client.db();
       const collection = database.collection("todos");
       const dataFromMongo = await collection.find().toArray();
       console.log(dataFromMongo);
   })
   .catch(error => {
       console.error("MongoDB connection error:", error);
   });
   ```
2. app.ts

   ```
   import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
   import { router } from "./routes/routes";
   import { mongoDBConnection } from "./database/data";

   const app = express();

   app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
   app.use(express.json());
   app.use("/", router);
   mongoDBConnection();

   app.listen(8000, () => {
       console.log("App is running at port 8000");
   });
   ```

I am getting error in the line

```
mongoDBConnection();
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mongoDBConnection` isn't a function so you can't call it.

So instead, try:

```js
export const mongoDBConnection = () => MongoClient.connect(
...
```